# How to retrieve Twitter username with UUID

Tags: social-network-analysis

I am trying to analyze [`FakeNewsNet`](https://github.com/KaiDMML/FakeNewsNet/blob/master/Data/BuzzFeed/User.txt) which is a fake news dataset for Social Network Analysis.

There are UUID(I am not sure about the entity name)s of users in the dataset but I am not sure how to retrieve metadata from it.

Can someone explain to me where I can find the information on how to use user_id of `User.txt`?

Is it even possible to retrieve the **metadata** of a user with this id? (may using Twitter Search API)

Reference: https://github.com/KaiDMML/FakeNewsNet/blob/master/Data/BuzzFeed/User.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with the current version of the dataset, the `User.txt` ids are hashed. But, the pre-processed features are in `UserFeature.mat` which you can load with something like

```py
import scipy.io
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('UserFeature.mat')
```

`mat['X'][0]` will then be the feature vector for the first user id in the text file.

There are no descriptions of the feature names either (or at least I didn't find any)